# pandas: INT Series, why there is ".0" after convert to string?

Tags: python, string, pandas, int, series

[image]

```py
df['advertiser_id'] = df['advertiser_id'].astype('str')
```

why there is a ".0" after convert to string?

```py
print(df['advertiser_id'].head())
OR
print(df['advertiser_id'][:-1].head())
# 
0     5677559.0
1     5834490.0
2     7218427.0
3    11193298.0
4    10901750.0
```

the questions is how to remove the ".0"?

Comment: Because you didn't convert to an int first

Comment: Check `df.dtypes`. I guess type of that column is float. That's why it is adding `.0`

Comment: @HarshaBiyani, yes, after fillna with 0, and convert to 'int' first, and convert to 'str',  then it worked. Thx!